# Get-Content Only Outputting Last Line

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach, getcontent

In my following code, I want it to output each AD group. However, it is only outputting the last AD group listed in the text file. How can I output each AD group?

```
$ADs = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\username\Documents\EditADGroupNotes.txt 

foreach ($AD in $ADs){
$ADGroup = Get-ADGroup -Identity $ADs | select name
}
```

Comment: Change `$ADGroup = Get-ADGroup -Identity $ADs | select name` to `Get-ADGroup -Identity $AD | select name`

Comment: I'm glad your problem is solved, but given that the problem was ultimately just a _typo_, your question and answer are unlikely to benefit future readers. Please consider deleting them.

Answer (score 1):

@olaf answered this.

Changed to:

```
Get-ADGroup -Identity $AD | select name
```